# DataGridView: How to enable multi row select but disable multi cell select?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0

I'm looking for a way to enable multi row select in a DataGridView-Control but disable multi cell select.

What I've tried so far:

- DataGridView.MultiSelect = true allows to select multi rows and cells
- ClearSelection() in DataGridView_CellMouseClick-Event and re-select the last selected cell doesn't look very nice (you see the old cell deselect and then the new cell select; SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout() doesn't help)
- DataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect is not an option: If the user clicks a cell, it should only this cell get selected

It's for an export function: The user should be able to export selected rows to a file but in general he should not be able to select more than one cell (for copy & paste etc.).

Regards,

inno

**----- [UPDATE] -----**

Here's my implementation. Works fine (comments removed for compactness):

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourAmazingNamespace
{
    public partial class SpecialSelectDataGridView: DataGridView
    {
        public SpecialSelectDataGridView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void SetSelectedCellCore(int columnIndex, int rowIndex, bool selected)
        {
            ResetSelectedCells();

            base.SetSelectedCellCore(columnIndex, rowIndex, selected);
        }

        void ResetSelectedCells()
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in SelectedCells) {
                base.SetSelectedCellCore(cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Multiple rows are selected through MultiSelect = true (default value) and currently selected cells are resetted by calling ResetSelectedCells() before selecting the new one.

HTH, thanks and regards,

inno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override [SetSelectedRowCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.setselectedrowcore.aspx) or [SetSelectedCelCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.setselectedcellcore.aspx) and perform your custom selection.

MSDN Quote:

> The DataGridView  control uses this
>   method whenever it changes the
>   selection state of a cell. The
>   selection state changes without regard
>   to the current SelectionMode property
>   value, and without changing the
>   CurrentCell property value. This is
>   useful when you want to implement your
>   own selection modes

Of course this means you will have to use an derived datagrid and not the standard one.